Using Excel to communicate to an Arduino to light 20 LEDs
I want to show progress on a wall using LEDs from data added in an Excel speed sheet.
I want to have about 20 different LEDs maybe more. Can this be done with an Arduino Uno?

You need to find out, if you can send data via Serial COM port in Excel via its macro language. I don't know and it would be out of scope here (since we are experts in Arduino, not Excel). If Excel is capable of that, there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Just googled it, if you write code in Excel VBA you can absolutely use a serial com port. So yes, it can be done

To add to that which chrisl has explained on the Excel side - on the Arduino side you would need a sketch that then reads the serial port and receives the info sent from Excel, decodes that data and triggers the LEDs correspondingly. If you can write that sketch and then have issues, then you can ask a more focused question regarding the Arduino code. However, as it stands, aside from just asking whether it can be done (to which the answer is "yes"), your question is otherwise too broad (if you also want to know how to do it).

Also, to light 20 LEDs you might need a multiplexer or decoder, as there probably aren't enough pins on an Arduino Uno for a one-pin-per-LED solution. Although, you could use an Arduino Mega, which has loads of pins - so you could have more than 20 LEDs (54 in fact) and still use a one-pin-per-LED solution.

@Greenonline The Uno has 20 pins: 0 to 13, A0 to A5. A bigger issue might be current consumption. Also a much better response would be to post an answer. Do you want this site littered with unanswered questions?

We get pestered by the Stack Exchange bot if questions go unanswered. So @chrisl and Greenonline, please help out by making actual answers.

@NickGammon -  I understand what you mean, but: D0 and D1 would be used by the serial port that the user needs; Every time I (or anyone) posts an answer it gets down votes by the (not so) mystery voter (we all know who it is); The question was about to be closed; The close vote limit needs to be increased from 3 to 5; The question was vague and/or broad, so an answer would have had to be long and rambling, thus it seemed better to offer a little partial guidance in the comments rather than no answer at all.  I like trying to help but this particular site seems to have some issues, sadly.

@NickGammon - If you want to reopen the question (I've just voted to reopen), I'll gladly put my comments in an answer (and take the -2 rep hit).. I could also add something about current consumption, unless you would like to post an additional answer about that (which might be better to be honest)

@Greenonline I've reopened it, and I'll upvote your answer to partly compensate for you-know-who. I agree you need the serial port for uploading sketches, but that doesn't really preclude you from using them for other purposes later. I also agree about the 5 votes, I thought we were doing something about that. You could mention the 74HC595 chip as an alternative way of doing it in your answer if you wanted.

the title is about Excel so if the answer is about the LEDs, the Q and its title should be edited. I couldn't decide which of existing Q&A about LEDs would be a duplicate, because of different ways how to do it. so the Q is too broad even if limited to the Arduino part.

@NickGammon - Ok, I think I've covered the basic principles, in my answer, without going down to design level (too broad). Thanks.

Hi this is my first question I have asked and the help that has been given is great.
this has given me loads to think about and loads to learn. thank you all for your help its really appreciated. always learning.

This really is a question of two parts:

"Can I communicate to the Arduino using Excel?", and;
"How can I light 20 LEDs using an Arduino Uno?"

Considering each aspect in turn...
Excel side
To add to chrisl's comment, which (partially) explained the Excel side:

... if you write code in Excel VBA you can absolutely use a serial com port. So yes, it can be done

Arduino side
Pin supply considerations
On the Arduino side you would need a sketch1 that then reads the serial port and receives the info sent from Excel, decodes that data and triggers the LEDs correspondingly.
Also, to light 20 LEDs you might need a multiplexer or decoder, as there probably aren't enough pins on an Arduino Uno for a one-pin-per-LED solution - there are twenty pins, but you will be using two of them (D0 and D1) for the serial communications via the serial port/monitor. Although, as Nick mentions in his comment, you could still use the Tx and Rx pins for the LEDs, but they would flicker during any serial communications.
With respect to using a multiplexer or decoder (there are a lot of different avenues that you could take2), as Nick also suggested, you might want to consider a shift register (such as a 74595).
Please refer to Serial to Parallel Shifting-Out with a 74HC595, from whence the schematic diagram below was sourced, for more information:



Current considerations
Using additional circuitry would also help alleviate another, as yet unconsidered, issue which is current draw. Unless you use low current LEDs, you might find the Arduino Uno struggling to supply sufficient current to power twenty LEDs.
Each pin on the Arduino Uno can supply 20 mA. However, the overall current draw should not exceed 200 mA..! Considering that one standard LED (whatever "standard" is or means) draws between 10 and 30 mA, so going for the low side, you could/might be able to light 20 LEDs. Nevertheless, you are nearing the limit and may be pushing it under certain scenarios. Using external "buffer" circuitry would prevent your Uno (and/or the regulator) from heating up and/or overheating.
Alternative Arduino solution
However, you could use an Arduino Mega, which has loads of pins - so you could have more than 20 LEDs (54 in fact) and still use a one-pin-per-LED solution.

Footnotes
1 If you can write that sketch and then have issues, then you can ask a more focused question regarding the Arduino code. However, as it stands, aside from just asking whether it can be done (to which the answer is "yes"), your question is otherwise too broad (if you also want to know how to do it).
2 Other methods of multiplexing include:

Charlieplexing, which allows you to control (n2 - n) LEDs with n pins, with little or no additional hardware/ICs. With 18 pins you could control 308 LEDs, although current supply issues would obviously arise, and need to be resolved.
Using a TLC 5940, 16-channel LED driver (which can be chained)

See also How can I effectively drive multiple LEDs with multiplexing?

LED matrix, I2C strips, Neopixels?

Comments have been moved to chat
